# can we use mysql with node.js

Tags: jquery, mysql, node.js

Can I use MYSQL like MongoDB with node.js for increasing the website speed.

Since Almost every popular programming language like Java or PHP provides driver to access and perform operations with MySQL.

Comment: Yes. many people uses mysql. It is not compulsory that you must use MongoDB. If your data is relational, you can use it.

Comment: can you share me the code example it will highly appreciable

Comment: Check this ; https://codeforgeek.com/2015/01/nodejs-mysql-tutorial/

Answer (score 4):

node-mysql is probably one of the best modules out there used for working with MySQL database which is actively maintained and well documented.

To install the MySQL node.js driver:

If you run just npm install mysql, you need to be in the same directory that your run your server. I would advise to do it as in one of the following examples:

**For global installation:**

> npm install -g mysql

**For local installation:**

1- Add it to your package.json in the dependencies:

```
    "dependencies": {
        "mysql": "~2.3.2"
    }
```

2- run npm install

> in my personal openion, mysql is slower than postgres and mongo db